# Tamir.SharpSsh Could not load file or assembly 'DiffieHellman

Tags: c#, ssh, sharpssh

```
private void OVConnection()
{
    try {
        //Create a new JSch instance
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Status>(DisplayStatus), Status.Connecting);
        //Create a new SSH session
        string host = "url"; //url
        string user = "***"; //ssh username
        string pass = "*******"; //ssh password
        int sshPort = 22; //ssh port
        int rPort = 3306;
        int lPort = 3306;

        int port = Convert.ToInt32(sshPort);

        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setHost(host);
        session.setPassword(pass);

        UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
        session.setUserInfo(ui);

        session.connect();

        //Set port forwarding on the opened session
        session.setPortForwardingL(lPort, "localhost", rPort);

        if (session.isConnected()) {
            MyDatabase();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Status>(DisplayStatus), Status.NotConnected);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Session.connect: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DiffieHellman, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'DiffieHellman, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.jce.DH.getE()
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.DHG1.init(Session session, Byte[] V_S, Byte[] V_C, Byte[] I_S, Byte[] I_C)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Buffer buf)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)

=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: DisplayName = DiffieHellman, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Development/2013/OV Projects/OmniView Documents Upload/Documents Upload/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Tamir.SharpSSH, Version=1.1.1.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

===

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Development\2013\OV Projects\OmniView Documents Upload\Documents Upload\bin\Debug\Documents Upload.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Development/2013/OV Projects/OmniView Documents Upload/Documents Upload/bin/Debug/DiffieHellman.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Development/2013/OV Projects/OmniView Documents Upload/Documents Upload/bin/Debug/DiffieHellman/DiffieHellman.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Development/2013/OV Projects/OmniView Documents Upload/Documents Upload/bin/Debug/DiffieHellman.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Development/2013/OV Projects/OmniView Documents Upload/Documents Upload/bin/Debug/DiffieHellman/DiffieHellman.EXE.
```

I can not figure out why.

Comment: You haven't included all of the relevant source code.  That aside, why aren't you using the .NET DiffieHellman implementation?

Comment: i inherited the code , this product has been working when i recompiled i get this error. what do you me relevant code, the code above is the first function called and i fails

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and was able to resolve it by adding [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiffieHellman/) from [Mentalis](http://mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=15) to my project references.

Make sure you have the [NuGet package manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca) installed, first. After installing it, I did this:

Right-click References > Manage nuget packages > search for DiffieHellman > Install

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I got same error but when i add dll DiffieHellman.dll and Org.Mentalis.Security.dll then it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void CopyfileToSFTP(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                
                log.Info("Started Copying file to sftp Server...");
                Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp sftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SFTPHost"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SFTPUserName"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SFTPPassword"));
                log.Info("sftp Server connecting");
                sftp.Connect(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SFTPPort")));

                log.Info("sftp Server connected");
                sftp.Put(filePath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPFileLocationPath"]);
                log.Info("sftp Server file pushed to location");
                sftp.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Info("Error : " + e.Message);
            }

            log.Info("SFTP server file writing Done..");

        }
```

I had the same error in production on this line
sftp.Put(filePath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPFileLocationPath"]);

By just copying DiffieHellman.dll and Org.Mentalis.Security.dll to deployed folder solved the issue.